# Concurrent random number generation

Tags: c++, random, openmp

I'm writing a parallel program using open mp in which I generate a matrix of random floating point numbers and then do a number of calculations on it. I currently want to make the step where I generate the matrix run in parallel, but I have the problem that the rand() function was not meant to run concurrently. I don't want to use locks to provide mutex on rand because this is the only thing being done in the loop and it would probably just be more efficient to run it sequentially. Is there any way to do this step efficiently in parallel?

Here if the current code for this part (with out mutex on rand);

```
#pragma omp parallel default(private)
{
    int i= omp_get_thread_num();
    for(int j=0; j<cols; j++)
        matrix[i][j]= rand()%1000 + (float)(rand()%100)/(float)(rand()%1000);
}
```

Comment: PRNGs generate a consistent sequence of numbers from a fixed seed.  Is this order (repeatability) important to you or do you really want "random"?

Comment: It doesn't matter if they are in any particular order, the problem I was having was when I ran it sequentially I got a pretty good spread across my range but when I changed it to parallel in general the numbers were less than 10 and when I sum up the rows almost all of them added up to 0 (I never got negatives with the sequential). This is making me think that there is some sort of concurrency problem with the function call.

Comment: Hold on a second -- once every thousand iterations on average, rand() % 1000 will be zero, so how can you divide by it?

Comment: Yes, and matrix and cols need to be shared, not private -- I assume this code is just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: yeah they are shared, but there all writing to different elements of matrix and rows and cols are constants so they shouldn't have any race conditions anyway. I did notice that changing i to a omp for along with rand_r over rows eliminated the race condition with the weird output though. @TonyK yeah and it was giving me inf for that position.

Comment: @Jonathan Dursi: If this code is just for demonstration purposes, then what it demonstrates is that user381261 is sloppy. You can't afford to be sloppy when you're writing parallel programs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using C++, you should consider using the [Boost library random number classes](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_random.html).  You can create a unique PRNG instance for each thread.  If you require repeatability, you can  initialize each instance in your main thread with repeatably generated seed values.

UPDATE: Turns out after I wrote this, C++11 was released and it included a more modern library for generating random numbers.  It includes [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) and [`std::std::uniform_real_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution), both of which rely upon a generator such as [`std::mersenne_twister_engine`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) (or a specific configuration `std::mt19937`).  As an example:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::mt19937 gen;  // Uses default seed value to generate repeatable sequence
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> d20(1,20);
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> prob(0.0, 1.0);

    std::cout << d20(gen) << std::endl;
    std::cout << prob(gen) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this modern library released in C++11 thread safe by default or does one need to protect the generator with mutex?

Comment: @AlBundy, I don't know for sure, but I'd be doubtful that it is.  Use of a thread lock can be avoided by ensuring each generator is associated with only one thread (which is the basis for the answer above) and each distribution is in turn associated with only one generator (which is guaranteed when they are created).  Each generator can be seeded differently to ensure they generate different sequences.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for `rand_r()`, which explicitly takes the current RNG state as a parameter.   Then each thread should have it's own copy of *seed data* (whether you want each thread to start off with the same seed or different ones depends on what you're doing, here you want them to be different or you'd get the same row again and again).

There's some discussion of `rand_r()` and thread-safety here: [whether rand_r is real thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772090/whether-rand-r-is-real-thread-safe) .

So say you wanted each thread to have its seed start off with its thread number (which is probably not what you want, as it would give the same matrix every time you ran with the same number of threads, but just as an example):

```
#pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(matrix, cols)
{
    int i= omp_get_thread_num();
    unsigned int myseed = i;
    for(int j=0; j<cols; j++)
        matrix[i][j]= rand_r(&myseed)%1000 + (float)(rand_r(&myseed)%100)/(float)(rand_r(&myseed)%1000 + 1);
}
```

Now each thread is modifying its own state exclusively (`rand_r()` is a pure function) and you should be home free.

Comment: That is the answer we need! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If pseudorandom is good enough (cf. Ben's comment), then you could create your own PRNG (eg. A Mersenne Twister rather than the weak modulo method used by most systems), and implement one independent generator per thread. if you do this, you MUST make sure that each generator has a different seed.

Answer (score 0):

A real problem is if you want reproducibility, which is often needed in test. With a given seed generate a sequence of thread seeds. Then each thread will use its own seed to generate numbers.

The fact that `rand()` is not thread safe is hardly an issue. There are plenty of algorithms available and is trivial to roll one instance (state) per thread, just start from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#Computational_methods for instance. Locking for each `rand()` call would be a concurrency disaster.