# How to generate random numbers in parallel?

Tags: c, random, openmp

I want to generate pseudorandom numbers in parallel using openMP, something like this:

```
int i;
#pragma omp parallel for
for (i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    printf("%d %d %d\n",i,omp_get_thread_num(),rand());
} 
return 0;
```

I've tested it on windows and I got huge speedup, but each thread generated exactly the same numbers. I've tested it also on Linux and I got huge slowdown, parallel version on 8core processor was about 10 time slower than sequential, but each thread generated different numbers.

Is there any way to have both speedup and different numbers?

**Edit 27.11.2010**
I think I've solved it using an idea from Jonathan Dursi post. It seems that following code works fast on both linux and windows. Numbers are also pseudorandom. What do You think about it?

```
int seed[10];

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
int i,s;
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    seed[i] = rand();

#pragma omp parallel private(s)
{
    s = seed[omp_get_thread_num()];
    #pragma omp for
    for (i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        printf("%d %d %d\n",i,omp_get_thread_num(),s);
        s=(s*17931+7391); // those numbers should be choosen more carefully
    }
    seed[omp_get_thread_num()] = s;
}
return 0; 
}
```

PS.: I haven't accepted any answer yet, because I need to be sure that this idea is good.

Comment: [`rand`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rand&sektion=3&format=html) is a very poor quality PRNG, it should only be use when compatibility is a requirement (e.g. to replicate a simulation run that used this exact same bad PRNG). Most operating systems / libraries provide better PRNGs (e.g. FreeBSD has [`random`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=random&sektion=3&format=html), [`lrand48`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lrand48&sektion=3&format=html), `arc4random`, etc).

Comment: Also, consider a counter-based PRNG such as the ones described in the paper ["Parallel Random Numbers: As Easy as 1, 2, 3"](https://www.thesalmons.org/john/random123/papers/random123sc11.pdf).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'll post here what I posted to [Concurrent random number generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234480/concurrent-random-number-generation/4234555) :

I think you're looking for rand_r(), which explicitly takes the current RNG state as a parameter. Then each thread should have its own copy of seed data (whether you want each thread to start off with the same seed or different ones depends on what you're doing, here you want them to be different or you'd get the same row again and again). There's some discussion of rand_r() and thread-safety here: [whether rand_r is real thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772090/whether-rand-r-is-real-thread-safe) .

So say you wanted each thread to have its seed start off with its thread number (which is probably not what you want, as it would give the same results every time you ran with the same number of threads, but just as an example):

```
#pragma omp parallel default(none)
{
    int i;
    unsigned int myseed = omp_get_thread_num();
    #pragma omp for
    for(i=0; i<100; i++)
            printf("%d %d %d\n",i,omp_get_thread_num(),rand_r(&myseed));
}
```

**Edit**:  Just on a lark, checked to see if the above would get any speedup.  Full code was

```
#define NRANDS 1000000
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    struct timeval t;
    int a[NRANDS];

    tick(&t);
    #pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(a)
    {
        int i;
        unsigned int myseed = omp_get_thread_num();
        #pragma omp for
        for(i=0; i<NRANDS; i++)
                a[i] = rand_r(&myseed);
    }
    double sum = 0.;
    double time=tock(&t);
    for (long int i=0; i<NRANDS; i++) {
        sum += a[i];
    }
    printf("Time = %lf, sum = %lf\n", time, sum);

    return 0;
}
```

where tick and tock are just wrappers to `gettimeofday()`, and tock() returns the difference in seconds.   Sum is printed just to make sure that nothing gets optimized away, and to demonstrate a small point; you will get different numbers with different numbers of threads because each thread gets its own threadnum as a seed; if you run the same code again and again with the same number of threads you'll get the same sum, for the same reason.  Anyway, timing (running on a 8-core nehalem box with no other users):

```
$ export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
$ ./rand
Time = 0.008639, sum = 1074808568711883.000000

$ export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
$ ./rand
Time = 0.006274, sum = 1074093295878604.000000

$ export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
$ ./rand
Time = 0.005335, sum = 1073422298606608.000000

$ export OMP_NUM_THREADS=8
$ ./rand
Time = 0.004163, sum = 1073971133482410.000000
```

So speedup, if not great; as @ruslik points out, this is not really a compute-intensive process, and other issues like memory bandwidth start playing a role.  Thus, only a shade over 2x speedup on 8 cores.

Comment: +1. I modified a little bit your solution and it seems to work good both on linux and windows.

Comment: As a beginner to openmp, was curious why you have explicitly declared "int i" before initializing in the parallelized for loop? Would anything go wrong if I ininitialized "i" in the for loop?

Answer (score 9):

You cannot use the C `rand()` function from multiple threads; this results in undefined behavior. Some implementations might give you locking (which will make it slow); others might allow threads to clobber each other's state, possibly crashing your program or just giving "bad" random numbers.

To solve the problem, either write your own PRNG implementation or use an existing one that allows the caller to store and pass the state to the PRNG iterator function.

Comment: +1. Very good. General idea is that rand() (and others) will lock the access effectively forcing threads to wait (making implementation close to single threaded or even slower) but never pointing at possibility to "...clobber each other's state, possibly crashing your program" which i saw in action!

Answer (score 4):

Get each thread to set a different seed based on its thread id, e.g. `srand(omp_get_thread_num() * 1000)`;

Comment: It's almost certain that this will not remove the slowdowns on Linux if there is not some logic that checks if the seed was initialized on all threads.

Comment: Explanation: http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/11/05/use-of-rand-in-openmp-parallel-sections/

Comment: @Axel That's probably because rand() has an atomic operation which it locks on. You'll have to look for a non-locking RNG.

Comment: I tried rand_r() to see if a reentrant version was faster (no locking), but it took the same amount of time on my system.

Comment: `rand` does not necessarily do locking, and should not. Calling it from multiple threads results in **undefined behavior**.

Comment: Axel was right, it didn't remove the slowdown problem on Linux.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like that `rand` has a global shared state between all threads on Linux and a thread local storage state for it on Windows. The shared state on Linux is causing your slowdowns because of the necessary synchronization.

I don't think there is a portable way in the C library to use the RNG parallel on multiple threads, so you need another one. You could use a [Mersenne Twister](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/mtwist.html). As marcog said you need to initialize the seed for each thread differently.

Comment: Indeed there is no portable way short of wrapping the call to `rand()` with your own mutex... which would rather defeat the purpose.

Comment: rand_r() is portable (in POSIX 1.c.) and reentrant.

Comment: I need to take a closer look at Mersenne Twister, because this method is not so obvious as most PRNG.

Comment: Jonathan, a reentrant rand function won't help to do parallel number generation because it requires synchronization. Tomek are you using pure C or C++?

Comment: I read the spec for rand_r and I was wrong. The seed is not a global state but given as a function parameter. So it would work, but it's not portable anyway.

Answer (score 3):

On linux/unix you can use

```
long jrand48(unsigned short xsubi[3]);
```

where xsubi[3] encodes the state of the random number generator, like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm> 
int main() {
  unsigned short *xsub;
#pragma omp parallel private(xsub)
  {  
    xsub = new unsigned short[3];
    xsub[0]=xsub[1]=xsub[2]= 3+omp_get_thread_num();
    int j;
#pragma omp for
    for(j=0;j<10;j++) 
      printf("%d [%d] %ld\n", j, omp_get_thread_num(), jrand48(xsub));
  }
}
```

compile with

```
g++-mp-4.4 -Wall -Wextra -O2 -march=native -fopenmp -D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL jrand.cc -o jrand
```

(replace g++-mp-4.4 with whatever you need to call g++ version 4.4 or 4.3)
and you get

```
$ ./jrand 
0 [0] 1344229389
1 [0] 1845350537
2 [0] 229759373
3 [0] 1219688060
4 [0] -553792943
5 [1] 360650087
6 [1] -404254894
7 [1] 1678400333
8 [1] 1373359290
9 [1] 171280263
```

i.e. 10 different pseudorandom numbers without any mutex locking or race conditions.

Comment: Could You elabrorate Your answer a little bit. I've never heard about jrand48, and I suppose this function is not is any standard library.

Comment: jrand48 is in the "family" of drand48() and lrand48().  It is part of the "Standard C Library (libc, -lc)", hence the #include<stdlib.h>.

Answer (score 0):

Random numbers can be generated very fast,so usually the memory would be the bottleneck. By dividing this task between several threads you create additional communication and syncronization overheads (and sinchronization of caches of different cores is not cheap).

It would be better to use a single thread with a better `random()` function.

Comment: This is probably not a good solution for me, because my program generates a lot of random numbers and it should concurrent.