# 10 dimensional Monte Carlo integration with openmp

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, montecarlo

I am trying to learn parallelization with openmp. I have written a c++ script which calculates 10 dimensional integration through MC for the function: 
F = x1+ x2 + x3 +...+x10

now I am trying to convert it to work with openmp with 4 threads. my serial code gives intelligible output, so I am kind of convinced that it works fine. 
here is my serial code:
I want to output for every 4^k iterations for N= number of sample points.

```
/* compile with 

               $ g++ -o monte ND_MonteCarlo.cpp 
               $ ./monte N

   unsigned long long int for i, N
   Maximum value for UNSIGNED LONG LONG INT 18446744073709551615
*/


#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


//define multivariate function F(x1, x2, ...xk)            

double f(double x[], int n)
{
    double y;
    int j;
    y = 0.0;

    for (j = 0; j < n; j = j+1)
      {
         y = y + x[j];
      }     

    y = y;
    return y;
}

//define function for Monte Carlo Multidimensional integration

double int_mcnd(double(*fn)(double[],int),double a[], double b[], int n, int m)

{
    double r, x[n], v;
    int i, j;
    r = 0.0;
    v = 1.0;


    // step 1: calculate the common factor V
    for (j = 0; j < n; j = j+1)
      {
         v = v*(b[j]-a[j]);
      } 

    // step 2: integration
    for (i = 1; i <= m; i=i+1)
    {
        // calculate random x[] points
        for (j = 0; j < n; j = j+1)
        {
            x[j] = a[j] +  (rand()) /( (RAND_MAX/(b[j]-a[j])));
        }         
        r = r + fn(x,n);
    }
    r = r*v/m;

    return r;
}




double f(double[], int);
double int_mcnd(double(*)(double[],int), double[], double[], int, int); 



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{    



    /* define how many integrals */
    const int n = 10;       

    double b[n] = {5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0,5.0};                    
    double a[n] = {-5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0,-5.0};  

    double result, mean;
    int m;

    unsigned long long int i, N;
    // initial seed value (use system time) 
    srand(time(NULL));  


    cout.precision(6);
    cout.setf(ios::fixed | ios::showpoint); 

    // current time in seconds (begin calculations)
    time_t seconds_i;
    seconds_i = time (NULL);

    m = 4;                // initial number of intervals

    // convert command-line input to N = number of points
    N = atoi( argv[1] );

    for (i=0; i <=N/pow(4,i); i++)
    {
        result = int_mcnd(f, a, b, n, m);
        mean = result/(pow(10,10));
        cout << setw(30)  << m << setw(30) << result << setw(30) << mean <<endl;
        m = m*4; 
    }



// current time in seconds (end of calculations)
    time_t seconds_f;
    seconds_f = time (NULL);
    cout << endl << "total elapsed time = " << seconds_f - seconds_i << " seconds" << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and output:

```
N            integral                                mean_integral
 4            62061079725.185936                      6.206108
 16            33459275100.477665                      3.345928
 64            -2204654740.788784                     -0.220465
 256             4347440045.990804                      0.434744
 1024            -1265056243.116922                     -0.126506
 4096              681660387.953380                      0.068166
 16384             -799507050.896809                     -0.079951
 65536             -462592561.594820                     -0.046259
 262144               50902035.836772                      0.005090
 1048576              -91104861.129695                     -0.009110
 4194304                3746742.588701                      0.000375
 16777216              -32967862.853915                     -0.003297
 67108864               17730924.602974                      0.001773
 268435456                -416824.977687                     -0.00004
 1073741824                2843188.477219                      0.000284
```

But I think my parallel code is not working at all. I know I'm doing something silly of course .As my number of threads are 4, I wanted to divide results by 4, and the output is ridiculous.

here is a parallel version of the same code:

```
/* compile with 

               $ g++ -fopenmp -Wunknown-pragmas -std=c++11 -o mcOMP parallel_ND_MonteCarlo.cpp -lm
               $ ./mcOMP N

   unsigned long long int for i, N
   Maximum value for UNSIGNED LONG LONG INT 18446744073709551615
*/


#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;


//define multivariate function F(x1, x2, ...xk)            

double f(double x[], int n)
{
    double y;
    int j;
    y = 0.0;

    for (j = 0; j < n; j = j+1)
      {
         y = y + x[j];
      }     

    y = y;
    return y;
}

//define function for Monte Carlo Multidimensional integration

double int_mcnd(double(*fn)(double[],int),double a[], double b[], int n, int m)

{
    double r, x[n], v;
    int i, j;
    r = 0.0;
    v = 1.0;


    // step 1: calculate the common factor V
    #pragma omp for
    for (j = 0; j < n; j = j+1)
      {
         v = v*(b[j]-a[j]);
      } 

    // step 2: integration
    #pragma omp for
    for (i = 1; i <= m; i=i+1)
    {
        // calculate random x[] points

        for (j = 0; j < n; j = j+1)
        {
            x[j] = a[j] +  (rand()) /( (RAND_MAX/(b[j]-a[j])));
        }         
        r = r + fn(x,n);
    }
    r = r*v/m;

    return r;
}




double f(double[], int);
double int_mcnd(double(*)(double[],int), double[], double[], int, int); 



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{    



    /* define how many integrals */
    const int n = 10;       

    double b[n] = {5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0};                    
    double a[n] = {-5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0,-5.0};  

    double result, mean;
    int m;

    unsigned long long int i, N;
    int NumThreads = 4;


    // initial seed value (use system time) 
    srand(time(NULL));  


    cout.precision(6);
    cout.setf(ios::fixed | ios::showpoint); 

    // current time in seconds (begin calculations)
    time_t seconds_i;
    seconds_i = time (NULL);

    m = 4;                // initial number of intervals

    // convert command-line input to N = number of points
    N = atoi( argv[1] );

    #pragma omp parallel private(result, mean) shared(N, m) num_threads(NumThreads)
    for (i=0; i <=N/pow(4,i); i++)
    {
        result = int_mcnd(f, a, b, n, m);
        mean = result/(pow(10,10));
        #pragma omp master
        cout << setw(30)  << m/4 << setw(30) << result/4 << setw(30) << mean/4 <<endl;
        m = m*4; 
    }



// current time in seconds (end of calculations)
    time_t seconds_f;
    seconds_f = time (NULL);
    cout << endl << "total elapsed time = " << seconds_f - seconds_i << " seconds" << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I want only the master thread to output the values.
I compiled with:

```
g++ -fopenmp -Wunknown-pragmas -std=c++11 -o mcOMP parallel_ND_MonteCarlo.cpp -lm
```

your help and suggestion to fix the code is most appreciated. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see what your program does. At `omp parallel`, your threads are spawned and they will execute the remaining code in parallel. Operations like:

```
m = m * 4;
```

Are undefined (and make no sense generally, as they are executed four times per iteration).

Further, when those threads encounter a `omp for`, they will share the work of the loop, i.e. each iteration will be executed only once by some thread. Since `int_mcnd` is executed within a `parallel` region, all it's local variables are private. You have no construct in your code to actually collect those private results (also `result` and `mean` are private).

The correct approach is to use a parallel for loop with `reduction` clause, indicating that there is a variable (`r`/`v`) that is being aggregated throughout the execution of the loop.

To allow this, the reduction variables need to be declared as shared, outside of the scope of the parallel region. The easiest solution is to move the parallel region inside of `int_mcnd`. This also avoid the race condition for `m`.

There is one more hurdle: `rand` is using global state and at least my implementation is locked. Since most of the time is spent into `rand`, your code would scale horribly. The solution is to use an explicit threadprivate state via `rand_r`. (See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287531/how-to-generate-random-numbers-in-parallel)).

Piecing it together, the modified code looks like this:

```
double int_mcnd(double (*fn)(double[], int), double a[], double b[], int n, int m)
{
    // Reduction variables need to be shared
    double r = 0.0;
    double v = 1.0;

    #pragma omp parallel
    // All variables declared inside are private
    {
        // step 1: calculate the common factor V
        #pragma omp for reduction(* : v)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j = j + 1)
        {
            v = v * (b[j] - a[j]);
        }

        // step 2: integration
        unsigned int private_seed = omp_get_thread_num();
        #pragma omp for reduction(+ : r)
        for (int i = 1; i <= m; i = i + 1)
        {
            // Note: X MUST be private, otherwise, you have race-conditions again
            double x[n];
            // calculate random x[] points
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j = j + 1)
            {
                x[j] = a[j] + (rand_r(&private_seed)) / ((RAND_MAX / (b[j] - a[j])));
            }
            r = r + fn(x, n);
        }
    }
    r = r * v / m;

    return r;
}

double f(double[], int);
double int_mcnd(double (*)(double[], int), double[], double[], int, int);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    /* define how many integrals */
    const int n = 10;

    double b[n] = { 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0 };
    double a[n] = { -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0 };

    int m;

    unsigned long long int i, N;
    int NumThreads = 4;

    // initial seed value (use system time)
    srand(time(NULL));

    cout.precision(6);
    cout.setf(ios::fixed | ios::showpoint);

    // current time in seconds (begin calculations)
    time_t seconds_i;
    seconds_i = time(NULL);

    m = 4; // initial number of intervals

    // convert command-line input to N = number of points
    N = atoi(argv[1]);

    for (i = 0; i <= N / pow(4, i); i++)
    {
        double result = int_mcnd(f, a, b, n, m);
        double mean = result / (pow(10, 10));
        cout << setw(30) << m << setw(30) << result << setw(30) << mean << endl;
        m = m * 4;
    }

    // current time in seconds (end of calculations)
    time_t seconds_f;
    seconds_f = time(NULL);
    cout << endl << "total elapsed time = " << seconds_f - seconds_i << " seconds" << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I removed the division by four, and also the output is done outside of the parallel region. The results should be similar (except for randomness of course) than the serial version.

I observe perfect 16x speedup on a 16 core system with `-O3`.

A few more remarks:

Declare variables as locally as possible.

If thread overhead would be a problem, you could move the parallel region outside, but then you need to think more carefully about the parallel execution, and find a solution for the shared reduction variables. Given the embarrassingly parallel nature of Monte Carlo codes, you could stick more closely with your initial solution by removing the `omp for` directives - which then means each thread executes *all* loop iterations. Then you could manually sum up the result variable and print that. But I don't really see the point.

Comment: I am still on the learning curve and thanks very much for detailed clarification

Answer (score 0):

I will not go into details but will give some pointers where to look at

Take for example this part of the code:

```
// step 1: calculate the common factor V
#pragma omp for
for (j = 0; j < n; j = j+1)
  {
     v = v*(b[j]-a[j]);
  }
```

If you look at variable v there is clear case of race condition. That is you have to declare v private to the thread (maybe call it local_v) and then through reduction operation gather all the values into a global_v value for example.

In general I would advise you to look for race condition, critical regions, concepts of shared and private memory for openmp.

Comment: While I can only second your general advise, the particular variable `v` is already private, as it is declared inside of the `parallel` region outside of the function.