# C++ with OpenMP try to avoid the false sharing for tight looped array

Tags: c++, arrays, ubuntu, openmp, false-sharing

I try to introduce OpenMP to my c++ code to improve the performance using a simple case as shown:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#define NUM 100000

int main()
{
    double data[NUM] __attribute__ ((aligned (128)));;

    #ifdef _OPENMP
        auto t1 = omp_get_wtime();
    #else
        auto t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    #endif

    for(long int k=0; k<100000; ++k)
    {

        #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static, 16) num_threads(4)
        for(long int i=0; i<NUM; ++i)
        {
            data[i] = cos(sin(i*i+ k*k));
        }
    }

    #ifdef _OPENMP
        auto t2 = omp_get_wtime();
        auto duration = t2 - t1;
        cout<<"OpenMP Elapsed time (second): "<<duration<<endl;
    #else
        auto t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
        cout<<"No OpenMP Elapsed time (second): "<<duration/1e6<<endl;
    #endif

    double tempsum = 0.;
    for(long int i=0; i<NUM; ++i)
    {
        int nextind = (i == 0 ? 0 : i-1);
        tempsum += i + sin(data[i]) + cos(data[nextind]);
    }
    cout<<"Raw data sum: "<<tempsum<<endl;
    return 0;    
}
```

Access to a tightly looped int array (size = 10000) and change its elements in either parallel or non-parallel way.

Build as

```
g++ -o test test.cpp
```

or

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -fopenmp
```

The program reported results as:

```
No OpenMP Elapsed time (second): 427.44
Raw data sum: 5.00009e+09

OpenMP Elapsed time (second): 113.017
Raw data sum: 5.00009e+09
```

Intel 10th CPU, Ubuntu 18.04, GCC 7.5, OpenMP 4.5.

<s>I suspect that the false sharing in the cache line leads to the bad performance of the OpenMP version code.</s>

I update the new test results after increasing the loop size, the OpenMP runs faster as expected.

Thank you!

Comment: how did you compile? Optimizations turned on?

Comment: `0.5 / 10000` is almost nothing. Try to increase the workload. Almost Nothing + overhead distributed on 10 cores is almost nothing + a lot more overhead.

Comment: I do not set -O3 or -O0, optimization settings kept as default.

Comment: default optimization is no optimization. Without optimizations it can be arbitrarily slow. If you care about runtime, always turn on optimizations

Comment: It seems that O3 optimization does not help too much. The difference between O0 and O3 under OpenMP conditions is 0.1s. You are right, maybe the workload does not cover the additional overhead.

Comment: I have 2 comments: 1) If you remove `schedule(static, 16)` the overheads will be smaller, 2) not only the workload is very small, but the code is memory bound.

Comment: Does memory-bound mean that fetching and flushing memory data is time-consuming, especially for a CPU with more than one core (implying potential CPU-CPU communication)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate random numbers in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287531/how-to-generate-random-numbers-in-parallel)

Comment: Your performance problems might have nothing to do with false sharing, but with using `rand` in parallel.

Comment: rand() just mimic a complex calculation process. This case is a minimal case, its prototype involves a very complex simulation situation, and I simplify it to a rand(). I really do not realize the if rand() works well for multi-thread code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since you're writing C++, use the C++ random number generator, which *is* threadsafe, unlike the C legacy one you're using.
2. Also, you're not using your data array, so the compiler is actually at liberty to remove your loop completely.
3. You should touch all your data once before you do the timed loop. That way you ensure that pages are instantiated and data is in or out of cache depending.
4. Your loop is pretty short.

Answer (score 1):

1. `rand()` is not thread-safe (see [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/#compatibility)). Use an array of C++ random-number generators instead, one for each thread. See [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_int_distribution/) for details.
2. You can drop `#ifdef _OPENMP` variations in your code. In a Bash terminal, you can call your application as `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 test`. See [here](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse50.html) for details.
3. So you can remove `num_threads(4)` as well because you can explicitly specify the amount of parallelism.
4. Use [Google Benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark) or command-line parameters so you can parameterize the number of threads and array size.

From here, I expect you will see:

1. The performance when you call `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 test` is close to your non-OpenMP version.
2. The array of C++ RNG generators is faster than calling `rand()` from multiple threads.
3. The multi-threaded version is still slower than the single-threaded version when using a 10,000 element array.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Referring to point 3, you said that OpenMP is slower than the single thread version using 10, 000 elements. I just tested it on my PC, the OpenMP costs about 10.69 s compared to the 41.503 s for a single thread. The data length is 10, 000 and the outer loop k ends at 100, 000.

Comment: I see you changed the "work" to `cos(sin(i*i+ k*k))` which will be independent calculations and, to me, looks like it is more effort than `rand()`. You also increased the loop length to 100,000 items which means the calculation should dominate over the thread setup/teardown costs. If, like your original code, your multi-threaded test used 4 threads then 10.69s for multiple threads versus 41.503s for a single thread sounds correct. Therefore, point 3 is no longer relevant.