# The problem with parallelizing the program using OpenMP

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I have a program that works with arrays and outputs a single number. To parallelize the program, I use OpenMP, but the problem is that after writing the directives, I started getting answers that are not similar to the answers of the program without parallelization. Can anyone tell me where I made a mistake?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

#define LOOP_COUNT 100
#define MIN_1_ARRAY_VALUE 1
#define MAX_1_ARRAY_VALUE 10
#define MIN_2_ARRAY_VALUE 10
#define MAX_2_ARRAY_VALUE 100
#define PI 3.1415926535897932384626433
#define thread_count 4

double generate_random(unsigned int* seed, int min, int max) {
    return (double)((rand_r(seed) % 10) + (1.0 / (rand_r(seed) % (max - min + 1))));
}
double map_1(double value) {
    return pow(value / PI, 3);
}
double map_2(double value) {
    return fabs(tan(value));
}
void dwarf_sort(int n, double mass[]) {
    int i = 1;
    int j = 2;
    while (i < n) {
        if (mass[i-1]<mass[i]) {
            i = j;
            j = j + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            double tmp = mass[i];
            mass[i] = mass[i - 1];
            mass[i - 1] = tmp;
            --i;
            if (i==0)
            {
                i = j;
                j = j + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("lab work 3 in processing...!\n");

    int trial_counter;
    int array_size = atoi(argv[1]);

    struct timeval before, after;
    long time_diff;
    gettimeofday(&before, NULL);

    for (trial_counter = 0; trial_counter < LOOP_COUNT; trial_counter++) {
        double arr1[array_size];
        double arr2[array_size / 2];
        double arr2_copy[array_size / 2];
        double arr2_min = DBL_MAX;
        unsigned int tempValue = trial_counter;
        unsigned int *currentSeed = &tempValue;
        //stage 1 - init

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(thread_count)
        {

#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(arr1, currentSeed, array_size) schedule(guided, thread_count)
            for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
                arr1[i] = generate_random(currentSeed, MIN_1_ARRAY_VALUE, MAX_1_ARRAY_VALUE);
                // printf("arr[%d] = %f\n", i, arr1[i]);
            }
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(arr2, arr2_copy, array_size, currentSeed, arr2_min) schedule(guided, thread_count)
            for (int i = 0; i < array_size / 2; i++) {
                double value = generate_random(currentSeed, MIN_2_ARRAY_VALUE, MAX_2_ARRAY_VALUE);
                arr2[i] = value;
                arr2_copy[i] = value;
                if (value < arr2_min) {
                    arr2_min = value;
                }
            }
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(arr1, array_size) schedule(guided, thread_count)
            for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
                arr1[i] = map_1(arr1[i]);
            }
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(arr2, arr2_copy, array_size) schedule(guided, thread_count)
            for (int i = 1; i < array_size / 2; i++) {
#pragma omp critical
                arr2[i] = map_2(arr2_copy[i] + arr2_copy[i - 1]);
            }
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(arr2, arr1, array_size) schedule(guided, thread_count)
            for (int i = 0; i < array_size / 2; i++) {
                arr2[i] = pow(arr1[i], arr2[i]);
            }
#pragma omp parallel sections
            {
#pragma omp section
                {
                    dwarf_sort((int) array_size / 2, arr2);
                }
            }
            double final_sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < array_size / 2; i++) {
                if (((int) arr2[i]) / 2 == 0) {
                    final_sum += sin(arr2[i]);
                }
            }
            // printf("Iteration %d, value: %f\n", trial_counter, final_sum);
        }
    }
    gettimeofday(&after, NULL);
    time_diff = 1000 * (after.tv_sec - before.tv_sec) + (after.tv_usec - before.tv_usec) / 1000;
    printf("\nN=%d. Milliseconds passed: %ld\n", array_size, time_diff);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Removing the C++ tag, as this is pure C (these are separate languages, and whilst OpenMP exists in both worlds, things would, from a design point of view, be handled differently than in your program).

Comment: oh, and by the way, `rand_r` is both not very fast and a pretty bad random generator. Also, the modulo method to limit the range of generated numbers will *not* yield good uniform samples. No offense (nothing that is usually well-taught!), but that `generate_random` is a bit of a "how to not do it" :) It doesn't matter much here, though (because the range is small, and your need for good randomness probably not very prominent)

Comment: @MarcusMüller. Thanks, I'll remember. But I need to use rand_r by assignment. The essence of the generator itself is to obtain pseudo-random numbers in order to check in the future whether the program is working correctly on one or more processors, as well as to check its execution speed.

Comment: As said, it's fine here :) It's more that this is a fairly complex program and I'm having a hard time understanding how it's parallelized.

Comment: FYI [How to generate random numbers in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4287531/10107454)

Comment: `omp parallel sections` with only one section doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Could you try to write better questions? 1. "the problem" is redundant because if you didn't have a problem you wouldn't be posting here 2 "with OpenMP" is almost redundant since you include the openmp tag, but if it's not, "with parallelizing" is redundant. 3 "the program" is very likely redundant too. If you do parallel programming there is always a program involved. How about "why do I get different random numbers in parallel"?

Answer (score 2):

`rand_r` is thread-safe only if each thread have its **own seed** or if threads are guaranteed to operate on the seed in an exclusive way (eg. using an expensive critical section). This is not the case in your code. Indeed, **`currentSeed` is shared between thread**. Thus, it causes a **race condition** since multiple threads can mutate it simultaneously. You need to use a thread-private seed (with a different value so for results not to be deterministic between threads). The seed of each thread can be initialized from a shared array filled from the main thread (eg. naively `[0, 1, 2, 3, etc.]`).

The thing is you will still get different results suing a different number of threads with this approach. One solution is to split your data set is **independent chunks** with an associated seed and then possibly compute the chunk in parallel.

Note that using a `#pragma omp parallel for` in a `#pragma omp parallel` section causes many threads to be created (ie. *over-subscription*). This is generally very inefficient. You should use `#pragma omp for` instead.